# Есть ли альтернатива CodeIgniter ?

Tags: фреймворк, php, codeigniter

Есть ли фреймворк, такой же простой в освоении, с такой же хорошей документацией, только развивающийся ?

Comment: yesod не подойдёт? (В вопросе про php не сказано, хотя соответствующий тег установлен)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

да, [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/)

> An elegant HMVC PHP5 framework that provides a rich set of components for building web applications.

Answer (score 4):

Больше всего рекомендую посмотреть [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/), есть ещё хорошие и развивающиеся фреймворки [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/), [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), и очень интересный и выделяющийся из всех [Phalcon](http://phalconphp.com/en/).

Answer (score 2):

Тут опять каждый будет хвалить то что нравится. Мой выбор [Laravel](http://laravel.com) переход с CodeIgniter был безболезненным. Но это опять ИМХО.

Comment: Сори что придираюсь, но выражение "мое [ИМХО][1]" звучит, как поездатый поезд.

  [1]: http://lurkmore.to/IMHO

Comment: ну да согласен поправил
извиняюсь